# Update radio button options after AJAX callback

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm working on a form that submits via an AJAX callback that handles some class-toggling and populates a results table.

Here's the callback that each input from the form calls:

```
public function myCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse;
    // Omitting for brevity: Call to an external API and get a JSON result set
    // Build a render array of results from API call and store in $content
    $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#results',$content));
    return $response;
  }
```

I now need to add a pager to the form results and I'd like to have the options update as a user adjusts the other filters. I can't seem to get my form to rebuild with new options, though.

Here's the pager element:

```
$form['pager'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => $this->t('Page'),
      '#options' => [
        // Number of options should update based on the response from the AJAX callback
      ],
      '#weight' => '2',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'myCallback'],
        'disable-refocus' => true
      ]
    ];
```

Is there any way to do this through an AJAX response?

Comment: Of course you can update radio buttons in an AJAX response, but you need to put them in $form before the AJAX callback is invoked.

Comment: @4k4 Thank you! I think I'm a little confused on the order of operations. My callback gets results with the pagination data from an external service. Where should I update $form so it gets updated before my callback?

Comment: Do all of this in buildForm(). I would put the result of the external API call also in $form and then deliver the entire $form or parts of it from the Ajax callback

Comment: @4k4 That was really helpful and I think I'm very close. It's updating values and returning results fine. However, the dynamic element only works on the first click. After it's replaced once with new options if you click it again the AJAX spinner appears but the ReplaceCommands don't work. All modifications to my form happen now in `buildForm()` and my callback just has two `ReplaceCommands` that return `$form['results']` and `$form['dynamic_field']`. Only the dynamic field doens't work. What might be going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Check in the browser debugging tools that the replaced dynamic field still has the css selector you are targeting in the replace command. And post the final solution so that the question gets answered.